# How do I add y-values with different x-values?

Tags: python, sum, numeric, curve

I have two curves that I want to sum. The x and y values are stored in arrays. The problem is, that the x values of the two curves aren't the same.

```py
x1 = [0.56, 1.06, 1.56, 2.06, 2.56]
y1 = [29.1, 27.3, 26.6, 24.7, 20.3]

x2 = [0.42, 0.92, 1.42, 1.92, 2.42]
y2 = [51.8, 43.6, 40.2, 36.4, 34.5]
```

Note, that the x-values are different but the interval between x-values stays 0.5.
Now how do i calculate the sum of the two curves similar to y1+y2=y3 but take the different x-values into account?[As you can see in the picture, I want to get the values of the new curve y3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/287KK.png)

Comment: You could create a new list of x-values `x3` that is the union of `x1` and `x2` and then interpolate `y1` and `y2` at those values. `y3` is then the sum of the interpolated `y1` and `y2`. You can use `numpy.interp` for the interpolation: [see the manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = [0.56, 1.06, 1.56, 2.06, 2.56]
y1 = [29.1, 27.3, 26.6, 24.7, 20.3]

x2 = [0.42, 0.92, 1.42, 1.92, 2.42]
y2 = [51.8, 43.6, 40.2, 36.4, 34.5]

# calculate the minimum x value
min_x = min(min(x1), min(x2))
# calculate the maximum x value
max_x = max(max(x1), max(x2))

# creating interpolator
p1 = lambda x: np.interp(x, x1, y1)
p2 = lambda x: np.interp(x, x2, y2)

x = sorted(x1+x2)
y1 = [p1(i) for i in x]
y2 = [p2(i) for i in x]

# calculator y3
y3 = [i+j for i,j in zip(y1,y2)]

plt.plot(x, y1, label='y1')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='y2')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='y3')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot! I slightly modified your solution: 
  1.  It doesn't seem like the min_x and max_x variables are used, so i omitted that part 
  of the code.
  2.  I only interpolated the y2 values for x1 values and then added y1 and the new y2 
 values over x1.